# How do I fix error "Service does not fully implement MICRService12 interface" when i try connect to TSP100LAN receipt printer under Linux

Tags: javapos

Details:
I try run example from star 1.3.6 packadge for linux x32.

I added to output all jar files and include all needed libraries

Next i try run

```
java -jar app.jar
```

and have next error

```
Open.
jpos.JposException: Service does not fully implement MICRService12 interface
    at jpos.MICR.setDeviceService(Unknown Source)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.Main.runTest(Main.java:199)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:241)
StarMICRTest finished.
```

I not changed any stars files but error say that star imlementation is not correct

When i tryed run my code with libraries from 1.3.4 packadge from Starmicronics, l has similar err

jpos.xml

```
<JposEntry logicalName="TSP100_Cutter_POSPrinter_Linux">
    <creation factoryClass="com.starmicronics.starjavapos.ServiceInstanceFactory" serviceClass="com.starmicronics.starjavapos.POSPrinterService" />
    <vendor name="Star Micronics" url="www.star-m.jp/eng/index.htm" />
    <jpos category="POSPrinter" version="1.13" />
    <product description="Star receipt printer" name="TSP100" url="www.star-m.jp/eng/index.htm" />
    <prop name="model" type="String" value="TSP100" />
    <prop name="portName" type="String" value="tcp:192.168.1.1" />
    <prop name="portSettings" type="String" value="" />
    <prop name="ioTimeoutMillis" type="Integer" value="5000" />
    <prop name="doCheckedBlockPrinting" type="Boolean" value="True" />
    <prop name="useNVBitImage" type="Boolean" value="False" />
</JposEntry>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed
for working with 1.3.6 pachadge config must be next

```
<JposEntry logicalName="TSP100_Cutter_POSPrinter_Linux">
    <creation factoryClass="com.starmicronics.starjavapos.ServiceInstanceFactory" serviceClass="com.starmicronics.starjavapos.POSPrinterService" />
    <vendor name="Star Micronics" url="www.star-m.jp/eng/index.htm" />
    <jpos category="POSPrinter" version="1.13" />
    <product description="Star receipt printer" name="TSP100LAN" url="www.star-m.jp/eng/index.htm" />
    <prop name="model" type="String" value="TSP100LAN" />
    <prop name="portName" type="String" value="tcp:192.168.1.1" />
    <prop name="portSettings" type="String" value="" />
    <prop name="ioTimeoutMillis" type="Integer" value="5000" />
    <prop name="doCheckedBlockPrinting" type="Boolean" value="true" />
    <prop name="useNVBitImage" type="Boolean" value="False" />
    <prop name="commandEmulatorConfig" type="String" value=""/>
</JposEntry>
```

and codesample must be getted from receipt_test instead MICR_test

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer was given, but i will share a similar problem i had with this error too and how did i solved it. Pretty easy really.

I am working on interface using JPOS for communicate with a Magellan Data logic Scanner and Scale that use a single USB OEM Cable, for scanner worked well, but when working with scale interface i got this error message:

"DL-Magellan-9400i-USB-OEM-Scanner-Scale profile, jpos.JposException: **Service does not fully implement ScaleService12 interface**"

checking in a more detailed way, i found that my hardware uses 2 different profiles inside jpos.xml file, one for scanner and another for scale, so my error was that i was using the scanner profile to connect to scale.

See:
i was trying to activate my scale using this profile (as you can see in highlighted text, it is for scanner):

[image]

so i found again in my xml file and found the correct one, that communicate with scale:

[image]

well, hope this can help someone else.